# How can i change a div's width and height when click a link outside of it?

Tags: javascript, html

As the title says i want to change the with and the height of a div when i click a link which is placed outside that div using JavaScript.

Right now i can change the div's dimensions ONLY when i click anywhere inside the div with the code above:

```
$('.greendiv').toggle(function(){
$(this).animate({'height': '300px', 'width': '400px'}, 200);
}, function(){
$(this).animate({'height': '200px', 'width': '200px'}, 200);
});
```

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KxpPR/2463/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to point out the class name where you would like the action to be performed

```
$('.clickme').toggle(function(){
    $('.greendiv').animate({'height': '300px', 'width': '400px'}, 200);
}, function(){
    $('.greendiv').animate({'height': '200px', 'width': '200px'}, 200);
});
```

Comment: your welcome please don't forget to vote and accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
$('.greendiv').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({'height': '300px', 'width': '400px'}, 200);
}, function(){
    $(this).animate({'height': '200px', 'width': '200px'}, 200);
});
```

```css
.greendiv {
  background: teal;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  
}
.clickme {color:#757575;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="greendiv"></div>
<div class="clickme">CLICK-ME</div>
```